# In what show were the little squealing wheeled robots that were disabled with champagne bottles?

Tags: story-identification, character-identification, episode-identification

I watched it probably between 1980ish to 1990ish. A group of people were being menaced by a set of small robots shaped like rectangular prisms that kind of squealed when they moved, like an electric motor spinning up. I remember the robots being taken out via champagne bottles (perhaps they weren't waterproof?) with the character shaking up the bottles and then spraying the robots with the foam.

I'm pretty sure that the robots had been shown to be deadly. I have this vague memory of someone getting cornered by them (a gameskeeper?) and then being shown dead, perhaps via electric shock.

Comment: Well, the 9th Doctor shook a bottle to shoot the cork at the Auton version of Mikey (episidoe: Rose).. And #10 used his screwdriver on a bottle to spray some gossipmongers in 'The Voyage of the Damned'... About the only non-drinking-non-gifting uses I can think of....

Comment: Could you be thinking of [cybermats](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Cybermat)?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: I thought of them early-on too, but the form doesn't match and I've yet to find a reference to champagne or them being vulnerable to liquids.

Comment: I wonder whether the board game we have at home might have them somewhere in it... I'll have to check BoardGameGeek when I get home.

Comment: Well, the only thing I can remember that was taken out by spraying it from a bottle is when the Seventh Doctor stuck the Kandyman to the floor with lemonade.

Comment: There was an episode of *The Avengers* (Steed and Mrs. Peel) that had little black boxes, about the size of a shoebox, that made an electrical crackling-squealing noise. It was earlier than the 80's, though.

Comment: @JoeL.: That might be it! It was probably a rerun on PBS and I confused it with Doctor Who because they also showed those episodes there. Do you remember which episode?

Comment: Joe has it... I would have sworn that was Doctor Who, but apparently it was The Avengers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This may be the *The Avengers,* 1969 season 5 episode [*Thingumajig:*](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0516947/plotsummary?ref_=m_tt_ov_pl)

> The vicar of a Norman church asks the Avengers' help when a team of archaeologists excavating a site underneath the church are all killed and their bodies rendered completely devoid of any energy. This is due to a little black box which sends out deadly charges of electricity. Furthermore its charges are nurturing a race of thingumajigs, pure energy creatures which will eat anything and must be stopped before they do great harm.

I don't remember the champagne, but a review of the episode on another site mentions it.

Comment: Well, I feel like an idiot that I confused the two shows. That would look to be it!

Comment: Season 7 according to the link provided.